# Why can't this JS loop return a variable from inside the function

Tags: javascript, html

With regards to the below code, I am trying to return a variable from inside of loop. I am calling the loop from inside of a function, however when the script is run I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: newVar is not defined".

Could someone explain why the value isn't being returned?

https://jsfiddle.net/95nxwxf4/

```
<p class="result"></p>

var testVar = [0,1,2];

var loopFunction = function loopFunction() {

    for (var j=0;j<testVar.length;j++) {
        if (testVar[j]===1) {
          var newVar = testVar[j];
          return newVar;
        }   
    }
    return false;
};

var privateFunction = (function privateFunction() {

  loopFunction();
  document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = newVar;
})();
```

Comment: document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML =loopFunction();

Comment: It is returned. But you are not doing anything with it: `loopFunction();`. http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html

Comment: FWIW, the IIFE is unnecessary as well as assigning to `privateFunction` (since the IIFE doesn't return anything).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the value returned from `loopFunction`:

```
var privateFunction = (function privateFunction() {

  var newVar = loopFunction();
  document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = newVar;
})();
```

Edit:

This is because the `newVar` assigned in `loopFunction` is scoped to that function, meaning it only exists inside that function.

Answer (score 0):

newVar is not defined because the scope of the variable newVar is only defined in the loopFunction.

a value is in fact being returned for the loopFunction, but it is just that, a value, the variable newVar has fallen out of scope and as such is not defined in this line.

```
document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = newVar;
```

change this to:

```
document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = loopFunction();
```